# Is it possible to convert an Azure storage blob file to a File class without saving the file?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have files in Azure storage that I am able to grab the Byte array data, but is there a way for me to turn this into a "File" object that is not stored anywhere that I can then ftp out?

Comment: Which `File` class? What are you trying to do? You should be able to easily use a stream / byte array.

Comment: Are you using blob storage or file storage as part of Azure Storage?